# Shall I set the timeout of "getting connection from pool"?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, httpclient, pool

In my current project, it will receive some messages from upstream systems, and upload them to another storage server by http service concurrently.

Since the system may receive many messages from upstream system at a short time, I use apache HttpClient with a pool, and, set:

1. If http client can't connect to storage server in 10s, it will throw exception
2. If http connection can't receive response from storage server in 10s, it will throw exception
3. If system can't get http connection from pool in 30 seconds, it will throw exception.

But my friend disagrees the 3rd point. She says, if the new messages can't get connections from the pool, just let them wait, since they will get a connection finally and save to storage server. The exceptions are not necessary in this case.

But I'm afraid that if we received too many messages from upstream, that there will be too many threads are blocking to wait connections, this may result the system unstable.

Do you think point 3 is good or bad? Do I need to set a timeout for it?

Answer (score 1):

> If system can't get http connection from pool in 30 seconds, it will throw exception.
>
> Do you think point 3 is good or bad? Do I need to set a timeout for it?

This seems very much to be a business decision and not a coding issue.  Is it okay for the request to wait for a long time for things?  Is it okay for the storage interface to throw an exception if some time expires?

If the storage-server is somehow hosed I'm assuming that all of the requests (that are able to get a connection) are waiting 10 seconds and then throwing. If you have enough connections in the queue then this may cause your persist operations to wait a long time to even get a connection.  Seems like a timeout is warranted but again this a business decision.

Generally, I would provide a timeout parameter (in seconds or millis) for the persist method to wait to complete.  Then the caller can pass in `Long.MAX_VALUE` if they want otherwise they will get an exception.  Or have another method that does not have a timeout parameter that is documented to chain to the other method with `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Another reason to have a finite limit on connection requests is to ensure that the application does not simply lock up in case of a connection leak. I would recommend having a large (say 10 minute) but finite timeout for connection lease requests. +1 otherwise.